# Convert series of .mp4 files to a slideshow?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

I recently wrote a little tool that helps me practice Chinese listening skills. It chops an input .mp4 file into a series of small .mp4 files, each having a single subtitle line in it. I'd like to share it with my teacher and I'm thinking of the best way to do that. The end goal is for her to be able to play them part by part in order, with the ability to replay each part as many times as needed. I imagine that a slideshow format would be best for that, because each video could be a slide. The problem is, there's a lot of those videos (hundreds/thousands, hundreds of megabytes total), so it would be best to have this automated.

As for the output format, I'm pretty open - it can be a PowerPoint presentation, LibreOffice Impress, or something else entirely - even if it's something that only works online. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

*Many* media players, such as VLC and MPC-HC, can read a [*file list* with extension *m3u*](https://www.leawo.org/entips/how-to-play-m3u-files-with-vlc-1398.html). This is the most flexible way to select and play videos in a specific order.

Simply open a text editor, such as Notepad. Add the filenames (without path, if the .m3u file is placed in the same folder as the videos) in sequence, and save with any filename but with m3u extension, such as *laguagepractice.m3u*.

Send all the video and m3u file in one folder. The viewer can simply watch in order, go to a previous file or skip a file with appropriate keybaord shortcut for [VLC](https://vlchelp.com/vlc-media-player-shortcuts/) or [MPC-HC](https://aboutdevice.com/mpchc-keyboard-shortcut-hotkeys/).

Comment: Nice solution, sir. And from a command prompt, DIR /B > LanguagePractice.m3u will produce a list of the file names for  you. You'd want to CD to the directory where your files are stored before running this command.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, Thanks for the tip on creating the m3u.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention:  > LanguagePractice.m3u will produce the .m3u file in the same directory as the MP4 files themselves and will include its own name in the resulting m3u file. Either edit that out or supply a full path after > to create the file in another directory.